# Way to link an swc externally

Tags: flash, apache-flex, actionscript

I have created a flex application and I want to use a third party library (swc) in such a way that

1. I won't have to include the third party swc in my swf at compile
   time. (I don't want the swc to be a part of my swf)
2. The end user will have my swf and the third party swc. He/She can link those two if required
3. In my application, the code which is using/importing third party library will work only if the end user decides to use third party swc, otherwise it'll be ignored.

Basically, I want to have an optional dynamic(runtime) linking to a locally stored swc at user end. If the swc is available, my swf should be able to use it else it doesn't have to.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about SWC but this is how I do it with SWF.
Please note I'm copying code from different parts so you may need to fine tune it

```
        var the_cls:Class;

        // First, load SWF with classes:
        var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest( u );
        var loader:Loader = new Loader();

        loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, function (e:Event){
            // then get class from the file, you can do it for few classes
            the_cls = e.target.applicationDomain.getDefinition("my_ldd_class_name") as Class;
        });
        loader.load(request, new LoaderContext(false, ApplicationDomain.currentDomain));



        // then use class in your application:
        the_obj = new the_cls();
        the_obj.the_func();
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Can you please tell me how to do it using an swf at runtime?